# Pre-trained Object Detection API model for greyscale images (1 channel)

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision, object-detection

I want to detect features, and possibly segmented them, in CT scan images (greyscale images) by means of the Object Detection API from Tensorflow. So I have two questions:

-Is there any pre-trained model within the Object Detection API that takes greyscale images as inputs for fine tuning training?

-Or, How can I train exisiting models, that are for RGB images, so that I can train them with greyscale images? Which modifications should be made in the code?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone would be interested in how I tackled this problem:

For segmentation of grayscale images, I found out this architecture: [U-Net](https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.04597)
The tensorflow adaptation by Akeret et al. can be found in [Github - UNet](https://github.com/jakeret/tf_unet)

I did not use API Object detection in the end since I was not sure how well the pre-trained models would perform in 1-Channel Images since they have been created for RGB-images.